# Rails N+1 because of .joins?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I got a simple search for posts in my rails app. It searches through taggings of the post and the content (body) of the post. Everything works finde, but bullet moans about a N+1 query.

```
N+1 Query detected Post => [:tags] Add to your finder: :includes => [:tags]
```

How can I avoid that in my situation? Code looks like that:

**model**

```
  def self.search(search)
    Post.joins(:tags).where("name LIKE ? or body LIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%").uniq
  end
```

**controller**

```
  def index
    if params[:search]
      @posts = Post.includes(:author).search(params[:search])
    else
      @posts = Post.includes(:author, :tags).all
    end
  end
```

If i use .includes instead of .joins, I get the following:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: name:
```

so, as a beginner, how to deal with that? Are there better solutions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The exception is pretty straight forward - does your Posts table have a `name` column? Perhaps you have forgot to run a migration or the column is named `title` or something else?

Comment: You also might want to re-write the query to explicitly target the posts table `.where("posts.name LIKE %:s% OR posts.body LIKE %:s%", s: search)`

Comment: Hi @max - no, my table doesn't have a name column. name refers to the joins table :tags. That's the reason, why i don't know how to use includes instead of joins ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell ActiveRecord which table you are using in the WHERE clause.

In most cases you would use a hash like this to target the associated table:

```
Post.includes(:tags).where(tags: { name: 'foo' })
```

When using LIKE however you need to create a string condition and in that case you would simply specify the table:

```
class Post
  # don't use an argument with the same name as the method.
  # its confusing and can lead to strange edge cases.
  def self.search(query)
    # Note that we use a named placeholder instead of ?
    self.includes(:tags)
        .where("tags.name LIKE %:q% OR posts.content LIKE %:q%", q: query)
        .uniq
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi @max, I tried your solution that sounds right but without any success. Then i figured out, that geocoder (I use it after that search query) can't handle includes (look here: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#known-issue). Now I use the suggestions there to use `.joins(:tags).preload(:tags).` Now bullet seems to be happy. Thank you for your answer, I'll mark it as right regardless.